# Flutter: Is it possible to auto-scale (whole) ui based on device size?

Tags: flutter

iOS native apps auto-scale the whole ui based on device size (width). Is there a similar behaviour with flutter?
I want to design a ui (with font sizes, paddings, etc) for a master device (iphone xs) and scale the whole ui to all other devices.
Wondering if that is possible as i couldn't find any information about it.
Just responsive sizing that needs me to configure breakpoints etc.

Comment: I don't think I understood your question correctly; Flutter already does that by default - of course, you can modify it a bit to make it more responsive. Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Hi @Kyle : Lets say i got a row with 4 cells (fixed height) that contain a specific amount of text (with line breaks) that just fit into these cells on iPhone XS Max . When i look at this on an iPhone 5 the cells shrink in size while the text (with a font-size that just worked on iPhone XS Max) now dissapears partially because it is not scaled down to fit into these cells.
Is this clearer? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

I usually obtain device size on Widget build, and then use a fraction of the width and height for each widget: Something like this:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
Size deviceSize;

class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  WelcomeState createState() => WelcomeState();
}

class WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color3,
      body: Container(
        height:deviceSize.height*0.5,
        width:deviceSize.width-50.0,
        child: Text("Welcome"),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this indeed is possible. All **you need** is **a** **ratio-scaling approach** with which you scale your entire GUI. Check out this **[ratio-scaling solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366247/3002719)** given to another SO answer relating to the **Flutter UI scaling** issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's  better to use MediaQuery.of(context).size, because while using external package, you won't be able to maintain the size of widgets on orientation change which might be a big downfall if your application required orientation change for better visual effects:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
AppBar appBar = AppBar(title: const Text("My Dashboard"));
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
    appBar.preferredSize.height -
    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top; // for responsive adjustment
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // for responsive adjustment
debugPrint("$height, width: ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.width}");
return Scaffold(appBar: appBar, body: ResponsivePage(height,width));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/scaled_app

Replace `runApp` with `runAppScaled`, the entire UI design will be scaled automatically.

Helpful when you want adapt to different screen sizes quickly