# How to make Text appear same on all screen sizes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know how I can make Text appear same on all screen sizes.

such that the text is scaled same on iPhone 5 and iPhone 11 Pro Max

Can somebody help me?

Further more what is best way to make a flexible UI in Flutter?

Comment: There is [this other SO question that could help (Sizing elements to percentage of screen width/height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122113/sizing-elements-to-percentage-of-screen-width-height)

Comment: The solution to this problem is: **1.** to **deactivate** (or override) the `textScaleFactor` property of texts, and **2.** **ratio-scall your entire UI**. A potential solution to this problem is given at [another UI-scaling SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819884/best-practice-for-effectively-scale-this-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes). Check it out - perhaps this solution works for you.